# See which CSS document there is used

Tags: html, css

I have to correct some text size. If you fx look at this page: the headlines are going out from the page on a mobile device, (or in the 'blisk' browser) so you have to scroll right to see the text.

The site has a lot of pages, and I cannot find the CSS or Sass file that is controlling the font.

Does anybody knows if I can see in the browser which document the `<h2>` tag is using. As I see it I cannot see it through the developer tools?

Comment: Any good devtools allow you to see applied rules.

Comment: Your css has been bundled, to see which css file it is in, you need to have a look in your developoment environment before the files are all bundled into one

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no way we can answer the question

Comment: Hit ctrl+u and a new tab will open showing you the html and what is called in the head

Comment: Thank you a lot. I understand that the question could be a guess to answer. But Pete already helped me here. So I know now that the CSS is bundled which I didnt do before. I am using Blisk to develop in. Otherwise it is Safari on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just one minified css

```
<link href="/bundles/css?v=SJ37P6CfqPJUAiVuLtUYrkvpJkXmJUlOWclWB_n1UKw1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The problem is here:

```
.h2, h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Since you have long words the browser try not to broke the words into multiple lines. You can decrease the font size for a certain breakpoint:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  .h2, h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I would like to learn is where can you see that is the problem. I am searcing around in googles developer tools under styles, but I cannot find what you find there? I can of course see the bundles, but where do you see that the problem is in h2?

Answer (score 2):

As Alessio mentioned the error lies in the h2 part.
If you switch over to developer tools you can see the width of certain html elements (some kind of overlay). In this case the h2 element goes over the border, which results in that scrolling problem. Your text or specifically this word "Søgemaskineoptimering" is too long and too big to fit in one line (mobile view). You can either change the font-size or set a wordbreak . Alessio already explained the breakpoint approach.

Best regards,
KN

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. The problem for me is now, that the page has so many different CSS files, SCSS files and JS files. So I am sitting with every document and go through the CSS to try find the h2. Is there a way where I can see which document the h2 tag is in?

Best regards.

Comment: Yes if you use the developer tool and inspect the h2 element, you will be able to see on the right side in the css box where the source is.
It will look like this:

.h2, h2 { css?v=SJ37P6CfqPJUAiVuLtUYrkvpJkXmJUlOWclWB_n1UKw1
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

Comment: Thank you a lot again. The problem is just that there is no document called css?v=SJ37P6CfqPJUAiVuLtUYrkvpJkXmJUlOWclWB_n1UKw1. Is that because the CSS gets minimized with the grunt file?

Comment: Yes if you go through the developer tool again you can literally click on that css file, which is under the "bundles" folder. My advice would be to copy that css snippet and just look for it through your css files to find out where it is located. Then again to fix it all you need to do is just to set a breakpoint in one of your css files and everything should look fine.

Comment: Ah okay now I understand. When a CSS file is minimized you can see the bundle under the tab: "Sources". I just tried to make a fiddle and made the code more nice: https://jsfiddle.net/j6809964/ . So I have to find the and make a breakpoint here: `.h2, h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}`

Comment: Well you dont have to find it just add the mentioned code from Alesssio regarding breakpoint at the end of your css file.

Comment: I tried to add the code like this https://jsfiddle.net/j6809964/1/ and build the project again. But the text is still the same size. I also tried to change the font-size without result.

Comment: Without looking though... Did you delete all your cookies ect.? You can check by using the developer tool again and see if your changed code is actually or specifically if the breakpoint was added in your css bundle.

Comment: The last line is: .blog-post{margin-bottom:55px}.blog-post-summary{border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;margin-bottom:20px} . So the end code should look like this: blog-post{margin-bottom:55px}.blog-post-summary{border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;margin-bottom:20px@media screen and (max-width:640px){.h2, h2{font-size: 10px;}}

Comment: .blog-post-summary{border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;margin-bottom:20px@media screen and (max-width:640px){.h2, h2{font-size: 10px;}} if this is really there the way it looks, then there is a } missing before your @ media thing. The css before is notclosed properly.